# left join with subquery with one result

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery, left-join

Here is a query:

```
SELECT 
k.[mg_KarId] AS [mg_KarId],
k.[SymKar] AS [SymKar],
k.[OpiKar] AS [OpiKar],
k.[Status] AS [Status],
kmlg.SymLok AS Lok_GLS1,
kmlk.SymLok AS Lok_KRS1,
kmlw.SymLok AS Lok_WLS1

FROM dbo.[mg_vv_Kar_All] AS k WITH (NOLOCK)

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT kml.SymKar, kml.SymLok
    FROM dbo.mg_KarMagLok kml
    WHERE kml.Mag LIKE 'GLS1' 
    ) kmlg ON k.SymKar = kmlg.SymKar
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT kml.SymKar, kml.SymLok
    FROM dbo.mg_KarMagLok kml
        WHERE kml.Mag LIKE 'KRS1'
        ) kmlk ON k.SymKar = kmlk.SymKar    
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT kml.SymKar, kml.SymLok
    FROM dbo.mg_KarMagLok kml
        WHERE kml.Mag LIKE 'WLS1'
        ) kmlw ON k.SymKar = kmlw.SymKar
WHERE k.Status <> 'W'
and k.SymKar = '0006438';
```

It gives me eight rows - 2 rows from every LEFT JOIN (2 * 2 * 2):

```
2002111576  0006438 CUKIER  A   R03-C-05    S07-A-08    WR03-19-01
2002111576  0006438 CUKIER  A   R03-C-05    S07-A-08    WR04-20-50
2002111576  0006438 CUKIER  A   R03-C-05    S07-A-09    WR03-19-01
2002111576  0006438 CUKIER  A   R03-C-05    S07-A-09    WR04-20-50
2002111576  0006438 CUKIER  A   R04-A-02    S07-A-08    WR03-19-01
2002111576  0006438 CUKIER  A   R04-A-02    S07-A-08    WR04-20-50
2002111576  0006438 CUKIER  A   R04-A-02    S07-A-09    WR03-19-01
2002111576  0006438 CUKIER  A   R04-A-02    S07-A-09    WR04-20-50
```

I just need only one row - no matter which one. I try to modify subquery in LEFT JOIN to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 kml.SymKar, kml.SymLok
    FROM dbo.mg_KarMagLok kml
    WHERE kml.Mag LIKE 'GLS1'
```

But it gives me NULL in main query at column Lok_GLS1. 
How should i resolve this problem?

Comment: If you don't care about the differences between the last three columns, why are you bothering to do all the subqueries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
k.[mg_KarId] AS [mg_KarId],
k.[SymKar] AS [SymKar],
k.[OpiKar] AS [OpiKar],
k.[Status] AS [Status],
(
    SELECT TOP 1 kml.SymLok
    FROM dbo.mg_KarMagLok kml
    WHERE kml.Mag LIKE 'GLS1' 
    AND kml ON k.SymKar = kmlg.SymKar
) ,
(
    SELECT TOP 1 kml.SymLok
    FROM dbo.mg_KarMagLok kml
    WHERE kml.Mag LIKE 'KRS1'
    AND k.SymKar = kml.SymKar
) ,
(
    SELECT TOP 1 kml.SymLok
    FROM dbo.mg_KarMagLok kml
    WHERE kml.Mag LIKE 'WLS1'
    AND kmlw ON k.SymKar = kml.SymKar  
) 
FROM dbo.[mg_vv_Kar_All] AS k WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE k.Status <> 'W'
and k.SymKar = '0006438';
```

You can think to use subquery and avoid 3 joins

Comment: Corrected to 'WHERE kml.Mag LIKE 'GLS1' AND k.SymKar = kml.SymKar' and thats ideal solution for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 1 kml.SymKar, kml.SymLok
FROM dbo.mg_KarMagLok kml
WHERE kml.Mag LIKE 'GLS1'
```

returns the `TOP 1` record from `dbo.mg_KarMagLok` *irrespective* of its correlation to `dbo.[mg_vv_Kar_All]` on `SymKar` field. Thus, it is most likely that the first `LEFT JOIN` fails, resulting in `kmlg.SymLok` (alias `Lok_GLS1`) being `NULL`.

If you want to use `TOP 1` in the subquery you have to substitute `LEFT JOIN` with `OUTER APPLY`:

```
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 kml.SymLok
    FROM dbo.mg_KarMagLok kml
    WHERE kml.Mag LIKE 'GLS1' AND k.SymKar = kmlg.SymKar AND
          kml.SymLok IS NOT NULL       
) kmlg(Lok_GLS1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't care about the last three columns in your result set, why not just do:

```
SELECT TOP 1
k.[mg_KarId] AS [mg_KarId],
k.[SymKar] AS [SymKar],
k.[OpiKar] AS [OpiKar],
k.[Status] AS [Status]

FROM dbo.[mg_vv_Kar_All] AS k WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE k.Status <> 'W'
and k.SymKar = '0006438';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve aggregation problem, you can group your data set.
Instead of using TOP keyword, write a query like this:

```
SELECT kml.SymKar, kml.SymLok
FROM dbo.mg_KarMagLok kml
WHERE kml.Mag LIKE 'GLS1'
group by kml.SymKar, kml.SymLok
```